# Using BeautifulSoup on list without losing url attributes

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, etl

I have successfully scraped a page for all of the li and created a dataframe.  The part I am having trouble doing is extracting and retaining the "url_for_rowN" part in each line. I want a .csv that captures two fields of text and the url that was applied to one of them; a sample format is in the code below.

A bonus would be if I could somehow capture the "date" from the h3 and retain that in the .csv, but all the list items in the page are in one  punctuated by inserted H3.

My current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#
# Sample format of file I want to extract 
"""
<h2>Date1</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Part1_of_row1: <a href="url_for_row1">Part2_of row1</a></li>
        .
        .
        .
        <li>Part1_of_rowN: <a href="url_for_rown">Part2_of rown</li>
<h2>Date2</h2>
        <li>Part1_of_rowNplus1: <a href="url_for_rown">Part2_of rowNplus1</a></li>
.
.

""" 
# Desired output is a .csv where each line has ["date","part1_of_rowN","Part2_of_rowN","url_for_rowN"]

with open("myfile.html", "r") as og_file:
    page = str(og_file.read())

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")

list_items = soup.find_all('li')

#separate each li in the soup object into columns
list_output = []
for li in list_items:
    company = li.find_all('span')
    row = [li.text for li in company]
    list_output.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(list_output, columns=["Company", "Role","C","D","E"])

#clean up some crap in the Company column
df["Company"] = df["Company"].str.replace(':','')
df["Company"] = df["Company"].str.strip()


with open('scrape.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    df.to_csv('scrape.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """\
<h2>Date1</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Part1_of_row1: <a href="url_for_row1">Part2_of row1</a></li>
        <li>Part1_of_rowN: <a href="url_for_rown">Part2_of rown</li>
<h2>Date2</h2>
        <li>Part1_of_rowNplus1: <a href="url_for_rown">Part2_of rowNplus1</a></li>
    </ol>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")


all_data = []
for li in soup.select("li"):
    d = li.find_previous("h2")
    d = d.text if d else "-"

    text1 = li.text
    text2 = "-"
    a = li.a

    url = "-"
    if a:
        text2 = a.text
        url = a["href"]
        a.extract()
        text1 = li.text

    all_data.append((d, text1, text2, url))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data, columns=["date", "part1_of_rowN", "Part2_of_rowN", "url_for_rowN"]
)
df["part1_of_rowN"] = df["part1_of_rowN"].str.strip(" :")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    date       part1_of_rowN       Part2_of_rowN  url_for_rowN
0  Date1       Part1_of_row1       Part2_of row1  url_for_row1
1  Date1       Part1_of_rowN       Part2_of rown  url_for_rown
2  Date2  Part1_of_rowNplus1  Part2_of rowNplus1  url_for_rown
```

Comment: I see the approach and I like it.  But with my data I get:
    text2 = li.a.text
                ^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @cube-convict That means, some of the list elements don't have `<a>` tag. I've updated my answer.